# Write a query to find the full names of those customers who have rented at least one movie and belong to the city Arlington

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am getting an error saying the output doesn't match for the given question

Sakila DB: `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure.html`

Below is my code

```
with temp as (
select concat(b.first_name, ' ',b.last_name) as name,
count(a.rental_id >= 1) as rental_count
from rental a
inner join customer b ON   (a.customer_id=b.customer_id)
inner join address c ON    (b.address_id=c.address_id)
inner join city d ON       (c.city_id=d.city_id)
where d.city like "Arlington"
group by name
order by rental_count
)
select name from temp
```

Expected Outcome is

```
full names of those customers who have rented at least one movie and belong to the city Arlington.
```

Could you please let me know what is the mistake or is there any other way?

Comment: In your data, how is someone a customer if they have not rented any movies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause, try the following

```
select 
    concat(b.first_name, ' ',b.last_name) as name
from rental a
inner join customer b 
on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
inner join address c    
on b.address_id = c.address_id
inner join city d       
on c.city_id = d.city_id
where d.city = 'Arlington'
group by 
    concat(b.first_name, ' ',b.last_name)
having count(a.rental_id) >= 1
```

Comment: Getting the error >> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from rental a 
inner join customer b ON 
a.customer_id = b.customer_id
inner join' at line 3

Comment: @PoornimaKeshavaiah try now, there was unnecessary `,`

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(first_name," ", last_name) as Customer_name
from rental
inner join customer
using (customer_id)
inner join address
using(address_id)
inner join city
using (city_id)
where city = "Arlington"
group by Customer_name
having count(rental_id) > 0
```